# When trying to install modules pip installs python3.5 even though 3.7 is already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When trying to install packages for `python3.7`, using the `pip install x` causes it to install python 3.5 and install the packages there instead.

This is for my Raspberry Pi Zero running the latest version of `dietpi`. I've tried re-installing Pip multiple times using different methods and all have produced the same result.

The code used to install `python3.7` and `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev -y
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
tar xf Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.0
./configure
make -j 4
sudo make altinstall
cd ..
sudo rm -r Python-3.7.0
rm Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
sudo apt-get --purge remove build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt install python3-pip

#The code to install the module
pip3 install pillow
```

I would expect Pip to install the module to `python3.7`.

Comment: You can try using `python3.7 -m pip install pillow` instead to install, thus specifying that you want to use the `pip` associated with `python3.7`. I know I had to do that when using WSL Ubuntu, otherwise `pip3` is associated with whatever other Python 3 is installed by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you ran `make altinstall` (not `make install`), the existing Python 3.5 installation remains the primary one. That is, `python3` and `pip3` still refer to interpreter and package manager of Python 3.5, while `python3.7` and `pip3.7` refer to Python 3.7. See: ["Installing multiple versions"](https://github.com/python/cpython#installing-multiple-versions) in the ReadMe of CPython's source repository. This is common practice as replacing the Python interpreter might break system tools that depend on it (or on the libraries installed along with it).